# How do I target this <a> in jQuery

Tags: jquery, focus, jquery-hover

Heres my jQuery

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.23/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script>
$('div.description a').focus(function(e){
    alert('asas');
});
```

Im trying to snag this little guy.

```
<body style="margin:0; text-align:center">

<div id="container">

    <div id="contentArea">
        <div class="cell">
            <a href="#"><img  class="gray" src="../images/kci.png" /></a>
        </div>
        <div class="cell">
            <a href="#"><img class="gray" src="../images/ksw.png" /></a>
        </div>
        <div class="cell">
            <a href="#"><img class="gray" src="../images/amc.png" /></a>
        </div>
        <div class="cell">
            <a href="#"><img class="gray" src="../images/cab.png" /></a>
        </div>


        <div class="description">
            <a href="">flyKCI.com</a>
        </div>

    THISS GUYY ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

        <div class="description">
            <a href="">Kansas Speedway</a>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

I want to target all a tags with the class description and then shoot out that alert when it is hovered over.. or is it focused on? either or. whatever.

Comment: If it's focused that means it is the element currently receiving keyboard input. If it's hovered over that means the mouse pointer is currently above it. Which do you want? Your current code already works for focus. (Hint: you don't want focus because then when the alert closes that will trigger another focus event which will trigger another alert...)

Answer (score 3):

> it is hovered over.. or is it focused on?

`on` `mouseover`:

```
$('div.description a').on('mouseover', function(){
    alert('asas');
});
```

**EDIT:**

It is not working because you have to load it on document ready or after the markup.

```
$(function(){
 //your script
})
```

Comment: still not alerting, is my jQuery and jQuery UI in the right order? Im nto getting any illegal chars or $ not defined errors, i think i have it right.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("div.description a").mouseover(function() { alert('asas'); });
```

will alert on a mouseover.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how to use the hover method:

```
$("td").hover(
  function () {
    $(this).addClass("hover");
  },
  function () {
    $(this).removeClass("hover");
  }
);
```

where the first function is your handler for the mouseenter event, and the second call is for the mouse leave event.